# Using gtest float comparison in Matcher

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I like to write a matcher for a structure which holds some float values:

```
struct Point3D
{
float x;
float y;
float z;
}

class Interface
{
virtual void SetPoint(Point3D point) = 0;
}

class MockInterface:
    public Interface
{
   MOCK_METHOD1(SetPoint, void(Point3D point));
}

MATCHER_P(Point3DEq, point, "Comparison of a Point3D")
{
   return point.x == arg.x && point.y == arg.y && point.z == arg.z;
}

TEST(Point3DComparison, TestIfPoint3DAreEqual)
{
   MockInterface interfaceFake;
   Point setPoint = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }
   EXPECT_CALL(interfaceFake, SetPoint(Point3DEq(setPoint)).WillOnce(Return());
}
```

I don't like this Matcher because he doesn't respected good float comparison. I would like to write a Matcher with using the Floating Comparison of gmock or gtest. It should look similiar to that.

```
MATCHER_P(Point3DEq, point, "Comparison of a Point3D")
{
   return EXPECT_THAT(point.x, FloatEq(arg.x) && EXPECT_THAT(point.y, FloatEq(arg.y) && EXPECT_THAT(point.z, FloatEq(arg.z);
}
```

The problem is that EXPECT_THAT is not returning any boolean value. Is there a nice clean way to do this using the functionality of gmock and gtest?

Answer (score 3):

nice way is to forget about `MATCHER_P`...

Use [`::testing::AllOf`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#composite-matchers) - and use proper matchers from gmock - like mentioned [`FloatEq`/`DoubleEq`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#floating-point-matchers-fpmatchers) - see:

```
auto Point3DEq(Point3D const& p_expected)
{
    using namespace testing;
    return AllOf(Field(&Point3D::x, DoubleEq(p_expected.x)),
                 Field(&Point3D::y, DoubleEq(p_expected.y)),
                 Field(&Point3D::z, DoubleEq(p_expected.z)));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how it works with the example. Iam not able to use this function as Matcher.

Comment: @PeterNL use exactly the same way as it would be defined by MATCHER_P - just `EXPECT_CALL(interfaceFake, SetPoint(Point3DEq(setPoint));`